# Table views from TOC in drop-down list in ArcPy - ArcGIS 10.5.1

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5

Just upgraded to ArcGIS 10.5.1 and trying to run my self-made Arcpy scripts but there seems to be a problem with the drop-down lists containing table views in this new version. The problem is that a drop-down list icon should appear in the right side of the box that shows all table views loaded in TOC.

However, I've noticed that this icon only appears when there are 1 or 2 dataframes in the document. When there are 3 dataframes (that's what I need and how I've been working with previous versions) the drop-down icon disappears and the only way to go is browsing through folders (folder icon) to find the db view, which by the way slows down a lot the scripts.

This is how it looks like when there are 3 dataframes loaded in the doc:

[image: Drop-down list not working]

And this is the right way (seen when removing one data frame from the doc):

[image: Drop-down list of table views]

I do not include any code because the example itself doesn't require it. It can be reproduced defining a parameter as "Table view" in an empty python script.

I'd like to know if someone else has noticed about this issue and if there is a simple way to fix it.